# Olympics java coding

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, instance

I am writing a program where i have to tally gold medals for each country. The input will come from a file and i have to process the file. **The first line is the country code, the second line is event type and third one is event.** The input is like this:

```
CHN 
Diving 
Women's 10m Platform 
CAN 
Rowing 
Men's Eight 
CHN
Rowing
Women's Quadruple Sculls
```

**The expected output should be like this:**

```
Count of gold medallists by country:
CHN - 2
CAN - 1

Count of gold medallists by event type:
Diving - 1
Rowing - 2
```

Okay so i have created a class of gold medals where it will create a new instance object for each country according to event type. My code is here:

```
class GoldMedals {
  private String country;
  private String eventType;
  private String event;
  private int medalCount;

 public GoldMedals(String name, String type, String event) {
   this.country = name;
   this.eventType = type;
   this.event = event;
   medalCount = 1;
}

public boolean matchDetails(String countryName, String type){
return (country.equals(countryName) && eventType.equals(type));
}
```

My main method is here:

```
try {
  input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("textfile.txt"));
  country = input.readLine();
  while(country!=null) {
    eventType = input.readLine();
    event = input.readLine();
    match = findMatch(winners, size, country, eventType);
    if(match == null) {
    winners[size] = new GoldMedals(country, eventType, event);
    size++;
      //match.addMedal();
    } //else {

        //match.addMedal();          
    //}
    //match.addMedal();
    country = input.readLine();
  }

  input.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
```

**I have also added a static method which will make sure that we are not creating objects that are already there. (redundant objects)**

```
public static GoldMedals findMatch(GoldMedals[] winners, int size, String country, String type) {
  GoldMedals result = null;
  int pos;

  pos = 0;
  while (pos < size && result == null) {
    if (winners[pos].matchDetails(country, type)) {
     result = winners[pos];
  } else {
     pos++;
  }
 }
  return result;
}
```

What i want to know is how can i get the required output. Cause **right now i am getting this output**:

```
ITA- 1- Fencing- Women's Individual Foil
POL- 1- Rowing- Men's Quadruple Sculls
KEN- 1- Athletics- Men's Marathon 
CHN- 1- Diving- Men's 3m Springboard
TUN- 1- Swimming- Men's 1500m Freestyle
CHN- 1- Canoe/Kayak - Flatwater- Canoe Double (C2) 500m Men
CHN- 1- Diving- Men's Synchronised 3m Springboard 
USA- 1- Gymnastics Artistic- Women's Individual All-Around
RUS- 1- Synchronized Swimming- Duet
```

which is what i have programmed. I need help with how i can get the total gold medals for each country as well as the gold medals according to event type. **In short how can i get the desired output which is above.**
I can further explain if you need help with my question. Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The easy way is to have 2 maps. The first to have a string like the country as the key and an integer to count the medals as the value. Second map should have a string of event for key and an integer counter for value. Than looping the file you will sum the medals for country and event. At the end a loop on the 2 maps will print your output.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The problem is i haven't gone too far into maps yet (which is my next target). I will have to learn maps in order to solve this problem. What i want to know is, how can i do it if i don't use maps. @MarioAlexandroSantini

Comment: Without maps you should create a class *MedalCounter* that contains 2 attributes, a string for a name and a counter than create 2 arrays of *MedalCounter*, one for the countries and one for the events.

Comment: so ill loop through the winners array of GoldMedals type and then do sth like this: `countryMedalCounter[start] = new MedalCounter(winners[i].country, 1) ` I still don't understand if i do like this, won't it take countries with different events twice. This will defeat the whole purpose unless i have taken your idea the wrong way. @MarioAlexandroSantini

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `medalCount` field. Your class should just represent the incoming data.

You then want to build two `Map<String, Long>` objects, where the key is country code or event type, and and value is the count for the key.

With Java 8 streams, it's fairly simple:

```
List<GoldMedals> allMedals = loadMedalsFromFile();

Map<String, Long> byCountry = allMedals.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GoldMedals::getCountry,
                                       Collectors.counting()));

Map<String, Long> byEventType = allMedals.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GoldMedals::getEventType,
                                       Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the time. As i replied to other guy, i don't know very much about maps. I need to do it without maps. (i'll be learning maps for my next project) Is there any other way i can solve it?

Comment: Can you please help me. i really need some help. i have been trying on my own from the past 2 hours.

Comment: I don't know what you have or have not learned. They wouldn't give you an assignment that can't be done with what you've learned, so you should be able to find a solution with what you know. Read over your material again. Maybe that will remind you of something that you're not thinking about.

Comment: i have been coding on my own all this time but i am getting null pointer exception. `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        
        String name = winners[i].getCountryName();
        if(!name.equals(countryArray[count].getName()))
            countryArray[count] = new MedalCounter(name, 1);
        else
            countryArray[count].updateCount();`

Comment: i made a new class called MedalCounter and created two array instances of that class. i am looping through the GoldMedal instances and creating new instances of MedalCounter if it is not there otherwise i just increment the counter. The MedalCounter has two instance variables called name and counter.

Comment: this is my stacktrace. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at A2Q1.findingCountries(A2Q1.java:67)
 at A2Q1.main  Can you please let me know why i am getting null pointer exception. findingCountries is the above class which will loop the array.

Answer (score -1):

In case you can't use Map. You can try the code below:

--GoldMedals

```
public class GoldMedals {
    private String country;
    private String eventType;
    private String event;
    private int medalCount;

    public GoldMedals(String name, String type, String event) {
        this.country = name;
        this.eventType = type;
        this.event = event;
        medalCount = 1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventType
     */
    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventType the eventType to set
     */
    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the event
     */
    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    /**
     * @param event the event to set
     */
    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    /**
     * @return the medalCount
     */
    public int getMedalCount() {
        return medalCount;
    }

    /**
     * @param medalCount the medalCount to set
     */
    public void setMedalCount(int medalCount) {
        this.medalCount = medalCount;
    }

    public boolean matchDetails(String countryName, String type){
        return (country.equals(countryName) && eventType.equals(type));
    }

}
```

--GoldByCriteria

```
public class GoldByCriteria {

    private String country;
    private int goldMedals;

    public GoldByCriteria() {}

    public GoldByCriteria(String country, int goldMedals) {
        this.country = country;
        this.goldMedals = goldMedals;
    }

    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    /**
     * @return the goldMedals
     */
    public int getGoldMedals() {
        return goldMedals;
    }
    /**
     * @param goldMedals the goldMedals to set
     */
    public void setGoldMedals(int goldMedals) {
        this.goldMedals = goldMedals;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((country == null) ? 0 : country.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        GoldByCriteria other = (GoldByCriteria) obj;
        if (country == null) {
            if (other.country != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!country.equals(other.country))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return country + " - " + goldMedals;
    }

}
```

--Util

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Util {

    /**
     * base on the criteria to get the number of gold
     * 
     * */
    public static final GoldByCriteria getGoldByCriteria(List<GoldByCriteria> list, String criteria) {
        for (GoldByCriteria goldByCriteria : list) {
            if(goldByCriteria.getCountry().equals(criteria)) {
                return goldByCriteria;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * group by Country
     * */
    public static final List<GoldByCriteria> getGoldMedalsByCountry(List<GoldMedals> goldMedals) {
        List<GoldByCriteria> result = new ArrayList<GoldByCriteria>();
        for (GoldMedals e : goldMedals) {
            GoldByCriteria goldByCountry = Util.getGoldByCriteria(result, e.getCountry());
            if( goldByCountry != null) {
                goldByCountry.setGoldMedals(goldByCountry.getGoldMedals() + 1);
            } else {
                GoldByCriteria oneGold = new GoldByCriteria();
                oneGold.setCountry(e.getCountry());
                oneGold.setGoldMedals(e.getMedalCount());
                result.add(oneGold);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * group by type
     * */
    public static final List<GoldByCriteria> getGoldMedalsByType(List<GoldMedals> goldMedals) {
        List<GoldByCriteria> result = new ArrayList<GoldByCriteria>();
        for (GoldMedals e : goldMedals) {
            GoldByCriteria goldByCountry = Util.getGoldByCriteria(result, e.getEventType());
            if( goldByCountry != null) {
                goldByCountry.setGoldMedals(goldByCountry.getGoldMedals() + 1);
            } else {
                GoldByCriteria oneGold = new GoldByCriteria();
                oneGold.setCountry(e.getEventType());
                oneGold.setGoldMedals(e.getMedalCount());
                result.add(oneGold);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

--Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<GoldMedals> goldMedals = new ArrayList<GoldMedals>();

        GoldMedals one = new GoldMedals("ITA", "Fencing", "Women's Individual Foil");
        GoldMedals two = new GoldMedals("POL", "Rowing", "Men's Quadruple Sculls");
        GoldMedals three = new GoldMedals("CHN", "Diving", "Men's 3m Springboard");
        GoldMedals four = new GoldMedals("CHN", "Diving", "Men's Synchronised 3m Springboard");

        goldMedals.add(one);
        goldMedals.add(three);
        goldMedals.add(two);
        goldMedals.add(four);

        //by country 
        List<GoldByCriteria> byCountries = Util.getGoldMedalsByCountry(goldMedals);

        for (GoldByCriteria goldByCountry : byCountries) {
            System.out.println(goldByCountry);
        }

        System.out.println("------------");
        //by Type

        List<GoldByCriteria> byType = Util.getGoldMedalsByType(goldMedals);

        for (GoldByCriteria goldByType : byType) {
            System.out.println(goldByType);
        }
    }
}
```

You should change the property "country" in GoldByCriteria to a better name like "criteria". For a quick code, I tested it with the country.

Hope this help.